# mysql calculating to get profit or loss from 2 tables ( Purchases and Sales) in FIFO mode

Tags: mysql, sql

how to calculate profit or loss from the 2 tables?

```
create table items(id int primary key auto_increment, name varchar(255));

insert into items value(null,'A');
insert into items value(null,'B');
insert into items value(null,'C');
insert into items value(null,'D');
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |

```
create table purchase(id int primary key auto_increment, item_id int,qnt int,price int);

insert into purchase value(null,1,10,20);
insert into purchase value(null,2,10,22);
insert into purchase value(null,3,10,25);
insert into purchase value(null,4,10,18);
insert into purchase value(null,5,10,25);
```

| id | ittem_id | qnt | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 20 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 | 10 |
| 3 | 3 | 10 | 10 |
| 4 | 4 | 10 | 10 |
| 5 | 1 | 10 | 25 |
| 6 | 2 | 10 | 16 |

```
create table sales(id int primary key auto_increment, item_id int,qnt int,price int);
insert into purchase value(null,1,2,25);
insert into purchase value(null,2,3,15);
insert into purchase value(null,1,3,26);
insert into purchase value(null,1,2,22);
```

| id | ittem_id | qnt | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 25 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 15 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 26 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 22 |

what I need is to put the cost of each item from the purchase table like this,(salesprice*qnt)-( costprice*qnt) as profit/loss

| id | ittem_id | qnt | price | cost | profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 25 | 40 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 15 | 30 | 15 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 26 | 60 | 18 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 22 | 40 | 4 |

no idea how to do it, right now I am doing this with PHP which takes too much time.

Comment: Do the ids correspond to dates? (e.g. do you know that id=1 in your purchase table happened before or at the same time as id=1 in your sales table?)

Comment: Why don't you care about the quantities in your purchase table? (i.e. in row 2 of your expected result, it seems odd that you are calculating profit and loss based on price=30, but you still have 8 "A"s that were purchased at 25.

Comment: yes, you are right, for example we buy item A many time, and sale it one by one, what I need to get profit or loss base my purchase price

Comment: I've answered your question with a mysql query and submitted an edit to remove the php tag as it doesn't seem relevant to php. If you really want a php solution I'd suggest opening a new question and showing the php code you have so far which could then be fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer your question as I understand it - this query should do the trick

```
select items.name as item, coalesce(sales_totals.total, 0) as total_sales, coalesce(purchases_totals.total, 0) as total_purchases, coalesce(sales_totals.total, 0) - coalesce(purchases_totals.total, 0) as profit
from items
left join
 (
    select item_id, sum(qnt*price) as total
    from purchase
    group by item_id
 ) purchases_totals on purchases_totals.item_id = items.id
left join
 (
    select item_id, sum(qnt*price) as total
    from sales
    group by item_id
 ) sales_totals on sales_totals.item_id = items.id;
```

This will yield the below output

| item | total_sales | total_purchases | profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 172 | 200 | -28 |
| B | 45 | 220 | -175 |
| C | 0 | 250 | -250 |
| D | 0 | 180 | -180 |

Some things to note

- Since this uses left joins to the purchases and sales tables based on the items table, and there are no 'E' items in the items table, it will not show any results for that item even if there are purchases or sales
- I have used a coalesce function on the subquery results in the outer select to allow records with no purchases or sales to return 'cleanly', ie, 0 instead of null

This can easily be expanded to include other calculations, as demonstrated below

```
select items.name as item, coalesce(sales_totals.total, 0) as total_sales, coalesce(purchases_totals.total, 0) as total_purchases, coalesce(sales_totals.total, 0) - coalesce(purchases_totals.total, 0) as profit, coalesce(purchases_totals.bought, 0) - coalesce(sales_totals.sold, 0) as stock_on_hand
from items
left join
 (
    select item_id, sum(qnt*price) as total, sum(qnt) as bought
    from purchase
    group by item_id
 ) purchases_totals on purchases_totals.item_id = items.id
left join
 (
    select item_id, sum(qnt*price) as total, sum(qnt) as sold
    from sales
    group by item_id
 ) sales_totals on sales_totals.item_id = items.id;
```

This adds in a a sum of 'qnt' in each of the subqueries which can then be subtracted in the parent query to provide a stock level

| item | total_sales | total_purchases | profit | stock_on_hand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 172 | 200 | -28 | 3 |
| B | 45 | 220 | -175 | 7 |
| C | 0 | 250 | -250 | 10 |
| D | 0 | 180 | -180 | 10 |

I leave it as an exercise for the reader to further modify the query to calculate the value of the stock on hand, which to me would be the logical next addition

Comment: Thank you sir, it helped me. if you can also solve my issue with fifo.

Comment: for example: I buy 10 item A 10$ each , then I buy 15 item A 12$ each, and now I sale 2 item 16$ each, what I need is to calculate sold item 2*16 total_sales, 2*10 as total_purchase because as fifo first I bought item 10$ till end each item

Comment: I can't imagine an easy way to do that with only sql. You mentioned in the question you'd attempted to do it with php, I'd suggest opening another question detailing what you've tried so far with your php code and that can be answered there